# Lost Permissions to Google Cloud Storage Bucket

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-storage

I accidentally deleted the "Storage Legacy Bucket Owner" permission on a bucket and now even though I'm the project owner and I created the bucket I cannot access it at all. What recourse do I have?

It seems like now no one at all has permissions on the bucket so it cannot even be deleted. It seems strange that Google Cloud Storage would allow you to get into the state of having a bucket that cannot be accessed or deleted by anyone. If I delete the whole project will the bucket be deleted? And is that my only option?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can regain access to the object by assigning an appropriate role, such as [*roles/storage.objectAdmin*](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles), to yourself or another member.

- Go to **IAM** under **IAM & admin** session
- **Add members**, and select **Storage > Storage Object Admin** role

Note that doing so provides access to all objects in the bucket or project.

You can see [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#best_practices) for more information.